# Make association with deepest rules from nested association

Tags: associations

I want to extract only the deepest level of association in a nested associations.

An example of input data is

```
<|a -> 1, b -> <|x -> p, y -> <|z -> 3, w -> "a"|>|>|>
```

and I need to get

```
<|a -> 1, x -> p, z -> 3, w -> "a"|>
```

I have seen several questions similar to this but I have not been able to solve the problem.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
test1 = <|a -> 1, b -> <|x -> p, y -> <|z -> 3, w -> "a"|>|>|>
Association[Level[test1 /. Association -> List, {-2}]]
(* <|a -> 1, x -> p, z -> 3, w -> "a"|> *)
```

**Update**

To address the comment about needing to handle the cases where the values of the lowest level associations might be lists...

```
test2 = <|a -> 1, b -> <|c -> 1, d -> {2, 3}|>|>
Association[Normal[test1] //. (_ -> val_Association) :> Splice[Normal[val]]]
(* <|a -> 1, x -> p, z -> 3, w -> "a"|> *)

Association[Normal[test2] //. (_ -> val_Association) :> Splice[Normal[val]]]
(* <|a -> 1, c -> 1, d -> {2, 3}|> *)
```

Probably want to bundle into a function:

```
AssociationLeaves[a_Association] := 
  Association[Normal[a] //. (_ -> val_Association) :> Splice[Normal[val]]]
```

Comment: Concise solution, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
asc = <|a -> 1, b -> <|x -> p, y -> <|z -> 3, w -> "a"|>|>|>

asc /. Association -> List // Level[#, {-2}] & // Association
```

> <|a -> 1, x -> p, z -> 3, w -> "a"|>

---

Or

```
Normal@asc //. {HoldPattern[a_ -> b_ /; ! AssociationQ[b]] :> a -> b, 
    HoldPattern[a_ -> b_ /; AssociationQ[b]] :> Normal@b} // 
  Flatten // Association
```

*Result:*

> <|a -> 1, x -> p, z -> 3, w -> "a"|>

Comment: Thanks!
The latter example was a little difficult for me, but I think I understand it somehow.

Comment: The latter seems necessary when the association contains lists as data. (ex) asc = <|a -> 1, b -> <|c -> 1, d -> {2, 3}|>|>;

Answer (score 3):

```
flattenA // ClearAll
flattenA[a_Association]     := Association @ Flatten @ KeyValueMap[flattenA] @ a
flattenA[k_, v_Association] := KeyValueMap[flattenA] @ v;
flattenA[k_, v_]            := k -> v

flattenA@<|a -> 1, b -> <|x -> p, y -> <|z -> 3, w -> "a"|>|>|>
```

> <|a -> 1, x -> p, z -> 3, w -> "a"|>

Comment: This gives `Association[
 Flatten[KeyValueMap[flattenA][<|a -> 1, 
    b -> <|x -> p, y -> <|z -> 3, w -> "a"|>|>|>]]]`.

Comment: @Syed sorry, made a typo, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

```
asc = <|a -> 1, b -> <|x -> p, y -> <|z -> 3, w -> "a"|>|>|>;

NestWhile[
 Association@
   KeyValueMap[
    If[AssociationQ@#2, #2, # -> #2] &, #] &, asc, UnsameQ, 2]

(* Output *)
<|a -> 1, x -> p, z -> 3, w -> "a"|>
```

Comment: also `FixedPoint[Association@*KeyValueMap[If[AssociationQ@#2, #2, # -> #2] &], asc]` (+1)

Comment: @kglr Nice one, thanks!